# Trouble understanding how voltage is applied across branches and nodes

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance

1.We are doing circuit analysis and college and I cannot fundamentally understand how voltage is applied across all of the branches and nodes when using Norton's or Thevinin's Theorem  to solve circuits. For eg, if finding the Norton's current across the short circuited node (where the load resistor was) , I just assume that the voltage of the source is the voltage across that node, but turns out it is not? I also assume  that the source voltage will be the voltage across all the resistors, but again turns out that is not the case. I understand that the voltage across a resistor will be equal to the source voltage if it is connected in parallel, but if the question has other configurations, I feel like I missed a step somewhere in my understanding. When we are using complicated nodal analysis methods, I am unable to figure out which voltage is unknown or which is known , because I think because I know the source voltage , I can just apply it. And having a bad teacher doesn't help. I was thinking if any of you would be able to point out my flaw in understanding.

2. Also, how do we intuitively know tricks like that of dangling resistors or short-circuited resistors, do they come from practice or are these to be systemically understood?

Comment: Adding a circuit diagram would make this question much easier to understand.

Comment: I myself was struggling to articulate it, but I will try to find one to illustrate it asap!

Comment: There are really two questions here, no?

Comment: You could draw one.

Comment: In any case, I struggled for a long time to get my head around this kind of thing, until I started thinking of the laws of physics (like Kirchhoff's laws etc.) as constraints. The equation $V = I R$ means that whatever the voltage may be, the current is related by that equation. Equivalently, whatever the current may be, the voltage is related by that equation. I find it helpful to think of the equation *without* any of the variables being "given"... the equation just is. In some circuits, we know the voltage from the beginning while in other circuits we know the current.

Comment: In a parallel circuit, a thing you know, i.e. another constraint, is that the voltages across the two branches are equal. You also know that the total current through all branches has to sum up to a value $I_\text{total}$ such that $V = Z_\text{parallel} I_\text{total}$ where $Z_\text{parallel}$ is, by definition, the impedance of the combined parallel branches.

Comment: yes, the second question is a more generic one. I thought I would just ask it here since its more of a soft question. Regarding the second question, I am still finding my feet in college and people here don't go into fundamentals which is leaving me with a gap in understanding. So I was just curious if any of you folks struggled this way too and whether you would know what to do

Comment: Being familiar with [ohm's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) might be helpful.

Comment: Your question needs clarity.  In the meantime do a Google search for Thévenin's theorem.